# Amazon SES send mail via CRONJOB getting error

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send newsletter/alerts to my site's users via Amazon SES using a CronJob.

I'm using the following php script to accomplish the delivery through SES

```
[http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-ses/?source=navbar][1]

include("ses.php");
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('id', 'key');
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$body="Test"
$m->addTo($mailId);
$m->setFrom('from@mail.com');
$m->addReplyTo('from@mail.com');
$m->setSubject('Reminder from Site.com');
$m->setSubjectCharset('ISO-8859-1');
$m->setMessageCharset('ISO-8859-1');
$m->setMessageFromString('text body',$body);
$ses->sendEmail($m);
```

But when I access this file (mailsend.php) via a browser, I'm getting e-mails pretty well. But when using this function triggered by a CronJob I'm getting the following error:

> [08-Jul-2013 11:10:11 America/New_York] PHP Warning: 
> SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 77 error setting certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>   CApath: none
>   in /home/site/public_html/files/login/ses.php on line 356

Ideas on where the problem could be?

Comment: cron's running as command line PHP, which has a different .ini file and generally different settings. compare `php -i` (command line)` and `phpinfo()` (browser) outputs and figure out which settings are different.

Comment: but I only have the cPanel access to the server. Can we check with cPanel access ?

Comment: As Marc B pointed out, the overall *environment* for a cron job (including the PHP version used) can be very different from running on a web server and accessing it via a browser. There appears to be some sort of authentication ("CA") problem when running under cron/command line. You may have to discuss this with your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code

```
$ses->enableVerifyPeer(false);
```

after

```
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('id', 'key');
```